# How can I achieve the effect of having a 1/4 circle close in on a background image without the image moving?

Tags: html, css

I have a square with a rounded corner. I need to animate the rounded corner closing in on an image. The image must not move, so the animation would appear as if the circle is "swallowing" the image.

Html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.circle {
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  background-image: url(http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/cache/8a/e0/8ae0d4f7338822ba567adfc22c54f1b6.jpg);
  background-size: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 1s all ease-in-out;
  position: relative;
}

.circle.closed {
  width: 0%;
  height: 0%;
  margin-left: 100%;
  margin-top: 100%;
}
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/peLrBG

As you can see, the image shrinks with the circle. I need the image to have no movement. How can I achieve this? Also, is there a better way to achieve a square with a rounded corner effect? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) CSS property that allows to achieve the desired effect.

```
.circle {
  ...
  clip-path: circle(50% at center);
}

.circle.closed {
  clip-path: circle(0 at center);
}
```